# Open USB camera with OpenCV and stream to rtsp server

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, stream, rtsp

I got a Logitech C920 camera connected via USB to a NVIDIA TX1. I am trying to both stream the camera feed over rtsp to a server while doing some computer vision in OpenCV. I managed to read H264 video from the usb camera in Opencv

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture cap;
    int heightCamera = 720;
    int widthCamera = 1280;

    // Start video capture port 0
    cap.open(0);


    // Check if we succeeded
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open camera" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Set frame width and height
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, widthCamera);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, heightCamera);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'));

    // Set camera FPS
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);

    while (true)
    {
        // Copy the current frame to an image
        cap >> img;

        // Show video streams
        imshow("Video stream", img);

        waitKey(1);
    }

    // Release video stream
    cap.release();

    return 0;
}
```

I also have streamed the USB camera to a rtsp server by using ffmpeg:
`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -timestamps abs -video_size hd720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy -c:a none -f rtsp rtsp://10.52.9.104:45002/cameraTx1`

I tried to google how to combine this two functions, i.e. open usb camera in openCV and use openCV to stream H264 rtsp video. However, all I can find is people trying to open rtsp stream in openCV.

Have anyone successfully stream H264 rtsp video using openCV with ffmpeg?

Best regards
Sondre

Comment: You can open USB camera using `cap.open(1);`, if you have a webcam in your laptop along with the USB camera.

Comment: You can use Gstreamer, if you've built OpenCV to support it.

Comment: I haven't got Gsteamer to work with H264. In ffmpeg H264 is natively supported

Comment: For video processing it's better to use FFMPEG

Comment: @user2594166 were you able to resolve the issue and would you be able to answer your question yourself today? Thanks!